google-cloud-sql network architecture upgrade error
I'm trying to run the network architecture upgrade that is required by google, but getting unhelpful results. We have three database servers in an HA configuration, but when upgrading two of them we get "invalid parameter". The command itself is very vanilla, so I'm not sure where it would go wrong. I added in verbosity debug to try and see what was going on, but wasn't much help.
$ gcloud sql instances patch db1-ha --upgrade-sql-network-architecture --verbosity debug

For one of them it succeeded, for the others I got:
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.sql.instances.patch] with arguments: [--upgrade-sql-network-architecture: "True", --verbosity: "debug", INSTANCE: "db1-ha"]
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): sqladmin.googleapis.com:443
DEBUG: https://sqladmin.googleapis.com:443 "GET /sql/v1beta4/projects/xxx-production/instances/db1-ha?alt=json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
The following message will be used for the patch API method.
{"name": "db1-ha", "project": "xxx-production", "settings": {"databaseFlags": [{"name": "default_time_zone", "value": "-05:00"}]}, "sqlNetworkArchitecture": "NEW_NETWORK_ARCHITECTURE"}
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): sqladmin.googleapis.com:443
DEBUG: https://sqladmin.googleapis.com:443 "PATCH /sql/v1beta4/projects/xxx-production/instances/db1-ha?alt=json HTTP/1.1" 400 None
DEBUG: (gcloud.sql.instances.patch) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 998, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 815, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/sql/instances/patch.py", line 411, in Run
    return RunBasePatchCommand(args, self.ReleaseTrack())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/sql/instances/patch.py", line 379, in RunBasePatchCommand
    result_operation = sql_client.instances.Patch(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/generated_clients/apis/sqladmin/v1beta4/sqladmin_v1beta4_client.py", line 936, in Patch
    return self._RunMethod(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 737, in _RunMethod
    return self.ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 743, in ProcessHttpResponse
    self.__ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 609, in __ProcessHttpResponse
    raise exceptions.HttpError.FromResponse(
apitools.base.py.exceptions.HttpBadRequestError: HttpError accessing <https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/xxx-production/instances/db1-ha?alt=json>: response: <{'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'date': 'Mon, 08 Apr 2024 03:37:27 GMT', 'server': 'ESF', 'cache-control': 'private', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'status': 400}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
>
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.patch) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.


Can you share your SQL instance configuration like disk size, --storage-auto-increase-limit etc?

I was able to stumble into the solution poking around for 4 hours:
The documentation for '--upgrade-sql-network-architecture' requires that the servers be in HA mode to do the upgrade. The database listing showed that HA was enabled, but when I went to the edit details it was listed as HA off.
After researching that, it appears there is a "legacy HA" that was enable when I first spun up the server which is no longer allowed, and does not constitute the 'HA' required for the upgrade. This is not listed in the documentation anywhere, and the error message certainly doesn't mention this.
Steps to resolve:

Disable HA on the primary server
Delete the secondary backup server
Enable HA on the primary server (this creates a new hidden backup server)
Rerun the upgrade listed in the original question.

